# how to handle large number of features machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

I developed a image processing program that identifies what a number is given an image of numbers. Each image was 27x27 pixels = 729 pixels. I take each R, G and B value which means I have 2187 variables from each image (+1 for the intercept = total of 2188).

I used the below gradient descent formula:

```
Repeat {
    θj = θj−α/m∑(hθ(x)−y)xj
}
```

Where `θj` is the coefficient on variable j; `α` is the learning rate; `hθ(x)` is the hypothesis; `y` is real value and `xj` is the value of variable j. `m` is the number of training sets. `hθ(x)`, `y` are for each training set (i.e. that's what the summation sign is for). Further the hypothesis is defined as:

```
hθ(x) = 1/(1+ e^-z)
z= θo + θ1X1+θ2X2 +θ3X3...θnXn
```

With this, and 3000 training images, I was able to train my program in just over an hour and when tested on a cross validation set, it was able to identify the correct image ~ 67% of the time.

I wanted to improve that so I decided to attempt a polynomial of degree 2.

However the number of variables jumps from 2188 to 2,394,766 per image! It takes me an hour just to do 1 step of gradient descent.

So my question is, how is this vast number of variables handled in machine learning? On the one hand, I don't have enough space to even hold that many variables for each training set. On the other hand, I am currently storing 2188 variables per training sample, but I have to perform O(n^2) just to get the values of each variable multiplied by another variable (i.e. the polynomial to degree 2 values).

So any suggestions / advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should have a look at stochastic (mini batch) gradient descent for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- try to use some dimensionality reduction first (PCA, kernel PCA, or LDA if you are classifying the images)
- vectorize your gradient descent - with most math libraries or in matlab etc. it will run much faster
- parallelize the algorithm and then run in on multiple CPUs (but maybe your library for multiplying vectors already supports parallel computations)

Answer (score 0):

Along with Jirka-x1's answer, I would first say that this is one of the key differences in working with image data than say text data for ML: high dimensionality.

Second... this is a duplicate, see [How to approach machine learning problems with high dimensional input space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255833/how-to-approach-machine-learning-problems-with-high-dimensional-input-space)