# Reuse dimensionality reduction after designing model with Matlab

Tags: matlab, svm, pca, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I'm using a binary classification with SVM and MLP for financial data. My input data has 21 features so I used dimensionally reduction methods for reducing the dimension of data. Some dimensionally reduction methods like stepwise regression report best features so I will used these features for my classification mode and another methods like PCA transform data to a new space and I use for instance 60% of best reported columns (features). The critical problem is in the phase of using final model. For example I used the financial data of past year and two years ago for today financial position. So now I want use past and today data to prediction next year. My question is here: Should I use PCA for new input data before inserting to my designed classification model? How can I use (For example Principal component analysis) for this data? I must use it like before? (pca(newdata…)) or there is some results from last PCA that I must use in this phase?

more information :

This is my system structure:
I have a hybrid classification method with optimization algorithm for select best features (inputs) of my model and best parameters of my classification method so for a classification method like MLP I takes long time to optimization with 21 features (beside of this I repeat every iteration of my optimization algorithm 12 times / cross section ) . So I want decrease the features with dimensionally reduction techniques (like PCA, NLPCA or supervised methods like LDA/FDA) before insert it to classification method. For example I’m using this structure of PCA code:

[coeff,score,latent,tsquared,explained,mu] = pca(*_*)

After that I will use 10 first columns of output (that sorted by PCA function) for input of my classification and optimization model. In final phase I will find the best model parameters with the best combination of inputs. For example my raw data has 21 features. After first phase of using PCA I will choose 10 features and in final model after optimization of my classification model. I will have a model with 5 best chosen features. Now I want use this model with new data. What must I do?

Thank you so much for your kind helps.

Comment: Can you post the code you had use? We have to help you directly with your code.

Comment: I don't think 21 features is a lot. Besides, SVM can handle high dimensional data easily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255833/how-to-approach-machine-learning-problems-with-high-dimensional-input-space

Comment: Hi. I add new information in above question. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow the following steps:

1. With your training data, create a PCA model
2. With the PCA of your training data, train your classifier
3. Apply the first PCA model to your new data
4. With the PCA of your new data, test the classifier

Here are some code snippets for steps 1 and 3 (2 and 4 depend on your classifier):

```
%Step 1.Generate a PCA data model  

[W, Y] = pca(data, 'VariableWeights', 'variance', 'Centered', true);
%# Getting the correct W, mean and weights of data (for future data)
W = diag(std(data))\W;
[~, mu, we] = zscore(data);
we(we==0) = 1;


%Step 3.Apply the previous data model to a new vector

%# New coordinates as principal components
x = newDataVector; 
x = bsxfun(@minus,x, mu);
x = bsxfun(@rdivide, x, we);
newDataVector_PCA = x*W;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Suppose that I choose first 10 features of output data from PCA in first phase (designing model). For phase 3 I must choose fist 10 features again (using model for new dataset)?

Comment: How can I obtain only 10 features in first phase? I must manually select 10 features?! Because I am using PCA for automatically dimension reduction.

Comment: No, you dont' have to. If you post your code, I can explain it better using your own example

Comment: thank you for reply. I added more information in above question.

Comment: My scripts are in 16 different files and a little complicated so I can’t put all these codes here.

Comment: The main idea is the one I showed you in the answer: use `coeff` and `score` to compute `W`,`mu`,`we`. Then,  use the first 10 columns as the input of your classifier. Then, during the testing, use the above code and use the first 10 columns of `newDataVector_PCA` as classifier input

Comment: Suppose that in phase 1, the input data has 20 features and 500 samples. After reducing the dimension we select 10 first best features. We import these features to hybrid classification method. This structure select for example column 1, 5, 8 and 10. ‘Data’ in code is a 500*20 dataset. The new data/Testing data is 300*20. This is our ‘x’ or ‘newDataVector’ in this code. Is this true? In final step we will select first 10 columns of newDataVector_PCA. newDataVector_PCA size is 300*20. After selecting 10 first columns now we have a 300*10 dataset. In this dataset we select 1, 5, 8 and column 10.

Comment: these columns are input columns of our designed model. is this true? Your help will be very useful for me. thank you again.

Comment: another question. in the code that you mentioned we have these scripts :

Comment: Another question. In the code that you mentioned we have these scripts:
X = newdataVector;
X = bsxfun(@minus,x,mu)
X = bsxfun(@rdivide,x,we)
newDataVector_PCA = X*W;
You normalized data before using it. So which structure is better? Normalized trading data and testing data before insert it to PCA or normalized it after insert it to PCA (or other dimensionally reduction techniques?). Witch normalization method is better? Max/min mapping or whitening for this propose?
Thanks.

Comment: Beside this you use mean and variance of last training dataset for normalize testing dataset? Why you use this approach?

Comment: @user3467834 First of all: before using ANY Machine Learning algorithm, please, read about it (you will understand why you need to "normalize" the test data using `we`and `mu` in PCA).

Comment: In reply to another of your comments: Now you have a matrix of training data 500*20. After you apply PCA (selecting 10 features), you will have a 500*10 data matrix as input of the train algorithm. You also have a 300*20 testing dataset. You HAVE TO apply the PCA model (`we` and `mu`, obtaining `newDataVector_PCA`) and then select the same number of features. So now you have a 300*10 testing dataset.

Comment: Thank you for answer again. About the above answer in the code you used mean and variance of training data for normalize data. Why you used this procedure? I think we must normalize testing data separately and calculate Transformed data by newDataVector_PCA = X*W (X is normalized data of testing sample)