# predict continuous target value from noisy input using machine learning approches

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a data in which each sample has feature vector consisting of x and about 9000 other features and also corresponding y(target value). in which x and y are both continuous values(between 0 to 20). x a noisy data but we can not recognize the source of the noise. The goal is to predict y from x and other features(features are not noisy). number of samples are about 900,000. what are the machine learning approaches I can use in this problem. also famous networks in neural network or deep learning.

Comment: I'm a little confused what you are looking for? Would you like suggestions on algorithms, configurations of algorithms, both?

Comment: I'm looking for algorithms or common machine learning approaches can be use to solve this problem. For example this problem can be seen as a regression problem but input data which is x is noisy that we don't have this property in regression. I want to know if there is a common method or algorithm in machine learning is like to solve this kind of problem or problems near this problem. if there is any I would appreciate to just name it.

Comment: In this case, I think you answered the question yourself. The first approach that comes to mind for me would be a neural network. The interactions between features of your dataset would determine the architecture of that network (so we can't comment there), and you would have a single output node that would handle the regression.

Comment: Do I read this correctly?  You're trying to predict Y from X alone, without using the other 9000 features?

Comment: Take a look at "How to approach machine learning problems with high dimensional input space?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255833/how-to-approach-machine-learning-problems-with-high-dimensional-input-space

Comment: @Prune No I will consider all features in this problem, but I separate x from the other in my explanation because just this feature is noisy

Comment: Excellent!  In that case, my answer below should be of some use to you.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me like a standard regression problem, although your prediction correlation is going to suck (technical term :-) ) in direct proportion to the noisiness of **x**.  Look up all the educational examples for predicting housing prices (often used to illustrate gradient descent).  You have 9000 features instead of 3 or 4, but that's just a matter of training time.

You might also consider some "factor analysis", so that you can eliminate the features that don't contribute enough to **y** (correlation coefficient near 0.0).  This is called "dimensionality reduction"; look for PCA (Principal Component Analysis).

Comment: Please provide wikipedia algorithms reference to the technical term `suck` . It would help my progress in ML.

Comment: Just a joke; I should have marked it as such.  :-)  It translates roughly as "exhibit unacceptable results and response".

Comment: Maybe a link to "using php for large scale ML"